# ¿Cómo actuar cuando una respuesta está bien pero no tiene explicación?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, colas-de-revisión, calidad-de-publicaciones

Últimamente veo bastantes respuestas que se cuelan en las colas de revisión (sobre todo en la de baja calidad) y las cuales están bien en cuanto a código se refiere (en muchos casos resuelven la duda del OP) pero que no tienen ningún tipo de explicación.

Hay varias alternativas dentro de la cola de revisión, entre ellas "Se ve bien" o "Eliminación recomendada" pero si pulso sobre "Eliminación recomendada" ninguna de las posibilidades se ajusta realmente al problema actual (está bien desarrollada pero falta una explicación al respecto). Por otra parte, me parecería una pena perder una respuesta que puede resolver el problema al OP simplemente porque no tiene una explicación sobre qué realiza dicho código.

En este punto, ¿qué deberíamos hacer para este caso concreto? ¿Sólo podemos dejar un comentario indicando al usuario que ha respondido que estaría bien que añadiera una explicación? ¿Y si el usuario no lo hace o no es muy activo y lo realiza al cabo de varias semanas?

Y si nos encontramos con este tipo de respuestas en la cola de baja calidad... ¿qué opción deberíamos elegir?

Comment: Probablemente sea útil pedir que lo revisen a los expertos en el lenguaje en cuestión. Si el código es bueno y útil para otros, pues se le puede añadir algún comentario. Si no vale un duro, se puede votar para borrar, así como indicar en comentarios.

Comment: Creo que se puede diferenciar en 2 tipos de casos, los que preguntan cosas y queda claro que "no entienden mucho" o "están empezando" y los más avanzados que están atascados en algo, en el primer caso creo que DEBE ir una aplicación pero no obligar a tal.. es más cosa del que responde, osea, ojalá lo explique pero sino no cuesta nada como usuario apoyar la respuesta si uno ve que es necesario.. en el segundo caso creo que si se es un usuario avanzado no tendrá problema en entender la respuesta si ésta responde efectivamente a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Yo a veces edito respuestas para añadir comentarios en el código. Sé que a usuarios con poca experiencia les cuesta entender el código cuando se vuelve un poco *arcano*, así que una respuesta con pocas o ninguna explicación pero con un código que corrige el problema no es demasiado útil, pero borrarla es una pérdida de recursos. El OP puede deshacer el cambio si no está contento, pero esto me ha pasado en muy contadas ocasiones, generalmente lo agradecen o no dicen nada.

Answer (score -2):

Aunque la pregunta se refiere a una respuesta que está bien, voy a empezar por el caso de cuando no lo está.

Dado que tienes mas de 10K no te preocupes por votar para borrar **una mala respuesta** con código "maravilloso". Si realmente es una joya, toma nota para que lo puedas encontrar después y en su momento compartir ese código con la debida atribución.

NOTA: Los usuarios con >=10K rep pueden ver las preguntas y respuestas eliminadas.

Ahora bien, me parece que en una revisión de respuestas debe tener prioridad es

1. Que la respuesta responda la pregunta

   - Si la respuesta está bien es porque responde la pregunta
2. Que la respuesta sea clara

   - Si la respuesta está bien es porque es clara

Si tienes dudas sobre si es clara o no, crea una pregunta específica aquí en meta para que otros te ayuden con eso. También puede ayudar mirar si el AP ha agregado comentarios a la respuesta en muchos casos eso ayuda a hacer un juicio.

Punto y aparte son las oportunidades de mejora que pueda tener una respuesta que está bien, por ejemplo, si puede hacerse aún más clara se podría agregar una explicación, sólo hay que estar seguros de que esta corresponde a lo que aporta la respuesta a resolver el problema.

Comment: No me acaba de convencer el argumento inicial: las respuestas no son para uno, sino para la comunidad. Borrarla _porque luego yo la podré ver igualmente_ no me resulta váildo, vaya. Además, que una respuesta borrada no es buscable.

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui por tu comentario. He agregado un enunciado introductorio para resaltar que el primer enuncia se refiere a respuestas malas, no a respuestas que están bien. Además he modificado un poco la redacción del último enunciado.

Comment: Qué bien, gracias. Sigo pensando que si es una _joya_, es mejor que se quede :) Abres una línea interesante aquí, que me hace pensar que si una respuesta es fantástica pero no responde, qué mejor que formular una pregunta ad hoc para que esa respuesta luzca. Pero lo mismo me estoy yendo un poco del tema que se trata aquí.

Comment: Hola Rubén gracias por comentar. Estoy con @fedorqui, realmente no termino de ver el "borra la respuesta porque yo la puedo ver". Hay muchos usuarios que son nuevos y no conocen el sitio, que están empezando y dan muy buenas respuestas (ya que el código encaja perfectamente con la pregunta y resuelve la duda del OP) aunque luego no haya explicación y no por ello lo consideraría una **mala respuesta**, solo que le falta un poco de maquetación. Igual se podría hacer que apareciera un mensaje al ir a contestar solamente con código o que directamente no deje enviar la respuesta si no hay

Comment: ningún tipo de explicación. La verdad es que cuando me paso por las colas de revisión es por el bien del sitio, no por el mío personal, y me hace duelo tener que votar para que se elimine una respuesta que con un poco de explicación sería fantástica.